# How to query post by pages in a <li> wordpress?

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress

Hi I am typically new on WordPress development I just do coding for my self, can you help me with this one?

I want to display my posts inside an li but the li will only contain 3 post item inside it. When the li is has already 3 items it will create another li so the another 3 post items will be there,

This is my code below and its not working properly, but I have an idea and I don't know how to make it the function called query post on WordPress the pagination type is it possible for example the first page will be the first li the 2nd page will be the 2nd li

```
                 <?php
             query_posts(array(
              'category_name' => '',
                 'post_type' => 'team',
                'posts_per_page' => 9,
                'paged' => (get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1)
            ));
            $x = 1;
            while (have_posts()) : the_post(); if ($x == 1) { ?>      
                                <li>
                                <?php } ?>

                  <div class="col-md-4 wp5">
                    <img src="<?php the_field( 'image' ); ?>" alt="Team Member">
                    <h4><?php the_field( 'name' ); ?></h4>
                    <p><?php the_field( 'intro_message' ); ?></p>
                    <div class="social">
                      <ul class="social-buttons">
                        <li><a href="<?php the_field( 'inkedin' ); ?>" class="social-btn"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="<?php the_field( 'twitter' ); ?>" class="social-btn"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="<?php the_field( 'email' ); ?>" class="social-btn"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                                              <?php if ($x == 3) { $x = 1; } $x++; ?>

                                </li>

            <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what the question is, however, if you want to have only 3 team (posts) per list item, your code will look like this:

```
             <?php
         query_posts(array(
          'category_name' => '',
             'post_type' => 'team',
            'posts_per_page' => 9,
            'paged' => (get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1)
        ));
        $x = 0;
        while (have_posts()) : the_post(); $x++; if ($x == 1) { ?>      
                            <li>
                            <?php } ?>

              <div class="col-md-4 wp5">
                <img src="<?php the_field( 'image' ); ?>" alt="Team Member">
                <h4><?php the_field( 'name' ); ?></h4>
                <p><?php the_field( 'intro_message' ); ?></p>
                <div class="social">
                  <ul class="social-buttons">
                    <li><a href="<?php the_field( 'inkedin' ); ?>" class="social-btn"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php the_field( 'twitter' ); ?>" class="social-btn"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php the_field( 'email' ); ?>" class="social-btn"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
       <?php if ($x == 3) { ?></li><?php $x = 0; } ?>

       <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: hi! thank u for answering but it has an error on this lien   <?php if ($x == 3) { ?></li><?php } ?> <?php $x = 1; } $x++; ?>  <?php endwhile; ?> By the way please check this I'm using this template: http://tympanus.net/Freebies/HalcyonDaysTemplate/ You can download it here: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/07/14/freebie-halcyon-days-one-page-website-template/ you can check the WE'RE A TEAM THAT ADORE WHAT WE DO section the slider has 3 item on a li,

Comment: Sorry, I'm getting used to stackoverflow. Anyway, the last update should do the trick..lol.